# file_get_contents not executing

Tags: php

I have made a template engine, which uses `file_get_contents()` to get the contents of a page then replace any keys it finds with the values.

That is not an issue, but what is an issue is that it makes a new output for the page, so it is something like this

```
$output = str_replace($key, $replace, $output); return $output;
```

The only problem is, in the new output, PHP code is shown in the source code and not ran. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: try using [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: I knw this is not the answer, but, if ur trying do a template engine... use a template engine like https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php :)

Comment: I'm attempting to make my own because it's a slight challenge for me, but the template engine part isnt the entire problem I'm guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get your code using `file_get_contents()`

```
$code = file_get_contents("page.php");
```

you do the work you need to do on the variable `$code` which is a string then you do this

```
eval($code);
```

if the code starts with html code and it has some php code inside  , try this

```
eval(" ?> " . $code . " <?php ");
```

I have to tell you that this is not a good solution, *eval* is the most risky function to use on php.

Comment: Thanks for responding, after using eval, I get this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\hk\cores\core.template_engine.php(62) : eval()'d code on line 1"

Comment: it means that the code you pass as argument on `eval` function is not correct

Comment: I don't mean to sound like a complete 'noob' here, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that, I never work with eval so I'm not sure how to work with it, I have really never found a user for it.

Comment: don't get me wrong, I meant when you do some work on the $code string, something went wrong, also try both `eval($code);` and `eval(" ?> " . $code . " <?php ");`. and finally, don't forget to set my answer as the correct answer. thank you :)

Comment: Neither of them worked, but I will do some work on the actual file I am trying to output then it should work fine (: I have used eval in the past but not enough to understand it fully, from what I already know(which is not really enough) I'm sure this answer will work :)

Comment: try to execute simple codes and then keep adding codes to your page until you get the result you need :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use PHP [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function to run a string as php code

```
$output = str_replace($key, $replace, $output); return $output;
eval($output);
```